# How do I conduct a regression on longitudinal data in Stata?

Tags: regression, stata

My data set contains data from a questionnaire taken at two time points (variable: Year, either 1 or 2). It looks something like this:

```
ID     Year    IQ    Active

1        1     124     Yes
1        2.    126.    No
2.       1.    133.    No
2.       2.    132.    No
3.       1.    107.    Yes
3.       2.    105.    Yes
```

I want to see whether increase in IQ over time (so from year 1 to year 2) is associated with an increase in physical activity (Individuals answering 'Yes' to the Active variable) over time.

How do I do this in Stata? I am pretty sure I need to do some kind of regression.

Comment: Have you considered using a paired t test?